# Regex python: match multi-line float values between brackets

Tags: python, regex, multiline, brackets

### Match grouped multi-line float values between brackets

> In the below example data, I want to extract all the float values between
>   brackets belonging only to "group1" using regex, but not the values
>   from other groups ("group2", "group3" etc.). A requirement is that it is done via regex in python. Is this
>   possible with regex at all?

### Regex patterns attempts:

I tried the following patterns, but they capture either everything or nothing:

> 1. Matches every float value in all groups: `([+-]*\d+\.\d+),`
> 2. Matches no value in any groups: `group1 = \[ ([+-]*\d+\.\d+), \]`

What should I do to make this work? Any suggestions would be very welcome!

**Example data:**

```
group1 = [
 1.0,
 -2.0,
 3.5,
 -0.3,
 1.7,
 4.2,
]


group2 = [
 2.0,
 1.5,
 1.8,
 -1.8,
 0.7,
 -0.3,
]


group1 = [
  0.0,
  -0.5,
  1.3,
  0.8,
  -0.4,
  0.1,
]
```

Comment: Do square brackets nest? If so, you need a pre-pass to deal with matching close brackets with open brackets, as regular expressions cannot "count" (you need a pushdown automaton, not just a finite state machine, to count matching brackets). If not, this should be do-able with a simple regex.

Comment: The brackets do not nest. It is always a flattened structure as given in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a regex I created `r'group1 = \[\n([ *-?\d\.\d,\n]+)\]'`:

```
import re

s = '''group1 = [
 1.0,
 -2.0,
 3.5,
 -0.3,
 1.7,
 4.2,
]


group2 = [
 2.0,
 1.5,
 1.8,
 -1.8,
 0.7,
 -0.3,
]


group1 = [
  0.0,
  -0.5,
  1.3,
  0.8,
  -0.4,
  0.1,
]'''

groups = re.findall(r'group1 = \[\n([ *-?\d\.\d,\n]+)\]', s)
groups = [float(f) for l in map(lambda p: p.split(','), groups) for f in l if f.strip()]
print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[1.0, -2.0, 3.5, -0.3, 1.7, 4.2, 0.0, -0.5, 1.3, 0.8, -0.4, 0.1]
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Thanks for sharing. It perfectly fits the requirements. I was spending a lot of time to find a perfect single regex pattern, but using a list comprehension to iterate over the match combined with the elegant lambda certainly does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\bgroup2 = \[([\s+\d+.\d+[,-\]]+)
```

This probably isn't the most optimized solution but I made it in just a few minutes using this website. http://www.regexr.com/

This is by far the best resource I have found yet for creating regular expressions. It has great examples, reference and a cheat sheet. Paste your example text and you can tweak the regex and see it update in real time. Hover over the expression and it will give you details on each part.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion and the regexr website. It is very useful. The answer from 'abccd' fits the requirements better though, because it extracts only the float values within the entire match. Your solution also contains spaces, comma's and the closing bracket.